# How do I italicize a crossed H?

Tags: accents, tipa

"Crossed h" (ħ) is a letter used in phonetics, as well as in the Maltese language, and some Semitic transcriptions. I would like to be able to display it, both upright and in italics.

`tipa` provides this character as `\textcrh`. However, unlike some other TIPA symbols, it can't seem to be italicized.

Bonus points if there's a method that works even if the font changes (by overlaying a bar onto the normal *h* glyph, for example)!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}

\LARGE

a\ng{}a\textcrh{}a

{
\itshape
a\ng{}a\textcrh{}a
}

The Hebrew word for ``spirit'' is \emph{rua\textcrh}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: TIPA specifically doesn't include an italic font since there is no practical use for it in linguistics (that may be a matter of opinion for some.)  Is a LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX solution an option?

Comment: Since 2018-12 LaTeX has `\hwithstroke` and `\Hwithstroke` for the Maltese letters (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/460110/35864, https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews29.pdf), but the italics look a bit ... off

Comment: @AlanMunn Sure, I'm willing to work with any TeX variant for this!

Comment: @moewe Oh, perfect! That would make a good answer

Comment: @marmot That does look correct, but including it in the middle of a word leads to ugly results (due to switching in and out of math mode).

Comment: LaTeX also has the math symbol `\hbar` for the Planck constant, but I don't recommend it here. I mention it for completeness.

Answer (score 8):

With either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX you can just type the letters directly into your source, and get italics the normal way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}

\LARGE

aŋaħa

{
\itshape
aŋaħa
}

The Hebrew word for ``spirit'' is \emph{ruaħ}.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 2):

You could “fix” `\hwithstroke` and `\Hwithstroke`, but beware that the parameters are font specific and these values are only good with Computer Modern.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\DeclareTextCommand{\Hwithstroke}{T1}
   {%
    \hmode@bgroup
    \vphantom{H}%
    \sbox\z@{H}%
    \ooalign{%
      H\cr
      \hidewidth
      \kern\strip@pt\fontdimen1\font\dimexpr0.9em\relax % <---- added
      \vrule
        height \dimexpr 0.7\ht\z@+0.1ex\relax
        depth  -0.7\ht\z@
        width  0.8\wd\z@
      \hidewidth\cr
    }%
    \egroup
   }
\DeclareTextCommand{\hwithstroke}{T1}
   {%
    \hmode@bgroup
    \vphantom{h}%
    \sbox\z@{h}%
    \ooalign{%
      h\cr
      \kern\strip@pt\fontdimen1\font\dimexpr0.33333em\relax % <---- added
      \kern0.075\wd\z@
      \vrule
        height \dimexpr 0.7\ht\z@+0.1ex\relax
        depth  -0.7\ht\z@
        width  0.4\wd\z@
      \hidewidth\cr
    }%
    \egroup
   }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

rua\hwithstroke

\textit{rua\hwithstroke} \textbf{rua\hwithstroke} \textbf{\textit{rua\hwithstroke}}

RUA\Hwithstroke

\textit{RUA\Hwithstroke} \textbf{RUA\Hwithstroke} \textbf{\textit{RUA\Hwithstroke}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Direct input is best, but you can use `tipa` commands for input, too.

With LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can use `tipa` commands with Unicode fonts if you use `xunicode` package instead of `tipa`.

[image: crossed h]

The `tipa` commands must be wrapped in a `\textipa{}` environemnt (e.g., `\textipa{a\ng{}a\textcrh{}a}`), and, as always, the font must contain the glyphs you want.

This method is double-handling, though. Direct input is recommended, if you have the keyboard overlay or a character-picker: aŋaħa *aŋaħa* **aŋaħa**.

Note that `CMU Serif` font does not have italic crossed-h.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tipa}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily\fipamain{Noto Serif}[Colour=blue]
\newfontfamily\fipa{Noto Sans}[Colour=red]
\newfontfamily\fipab{CMU Serif}

\providecommand\XeTeXpicfile{ROSS, grmmble:-)}% with luatex that means "pretending" to be xetex just while you load the package
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357686/does-fontspec-no-longer-provide-the-textipa-command
\usepackage{xunicode}
\def\useTIPAfont{\fipamain}%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358118/tipa-tone-bar-glyph-missing-with-xecjk



\begin{document}

\LARGE
\textipa{a\ng{}a\textcrh{}a}

{
\itshape
\textipa{a\ng{}a\textcrh{}a}
}

The Hebrew word for ``spirit'' is \emph{\textipa{rua\textcrh}}.

\def\useTIPAfont{\fipa}

\textipa{a\ng{}a\textcrh{}a}

{
\itshape
\textipa{a\ng{}a\textcrh{}a}
}

The Hebrew word for ``spirit'' is \emph{\textipa{rua\textcrh}}.

\def\useTIPAfont{\fipab} Using CMU Serif: 
\textipa{a\ng{}a\textcrh{}a}
{
\itshape
\textipa{a\ng{}a\textcrh{}a}
}

\end{document}
```